# Upload file using Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.3

I want to upload file in my app.
This is the blade file .

```
<form action="/fileUploader " files="true" method="post" role="form" name="file" id="chan" >
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <label>Please Select a File to Upload</label>
             <input type="image">
             <button type="submit" name ="Upload_File">Upload File</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is my controller file

```
public function viewFile()
 {
     return View::make('/fileUploader');
 }

    public function showfileupload(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request -> file('image');
        // show the file name
        echo 'File Name : '.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        echo '<br>';

        // show file extensions
        echo 'File Extensions : '.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        echo '<br>';

        // show file path
        echo 'File Path : '.$file->getRealPath();
        echo '<br>';

        // show file size
        echo 'File Size : '.$file->getSize();
        echo '<br>';

        // show file mime type
        echo 'File Mime Type : '.$file->getMimeType();
        echo '<br>';

        // move uploaded File
        $destinationPath = 'uploads';
        $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
```

This is the web.php file

```
Route::get('/fileUploader', 'channelController@viewFile');
Route::post('/fileUploader', 'channelController@showfileupload');
```

I'm getting an error called FatalThrowableError in channelController.php line 48:
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null.

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are trying to call a method - `getClientOriginalName()` - on a object that doesn't exist, so it's null. That jives with the error message you are seeing.

I'm not sure why, but we can start working backwards.  Let's use an if statement with the `hasFile()` method to verify that a file is actually present on the request before attempting to `move()` it.

```php
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

If you implement the above, does the error still exist?

Here are the [Laravel 5.3 Docs on file uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#files). It may give you some more ideas.

If you're finding that users are posting files and `hasFile()` is still returning boolean FALSE, then you may want to go digging into the php.ini file and take a look at the `Post_max_size` or `upload_max_size values` to make sure that we aren't blocking large uploads.

Answer (score 0):

**VIEW**

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'fileUploader', 'id'=>'chan', 'files' => true] )!!}

        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <label>Please Select a File to Upload</label>
                 <input type="file" name="image">
            <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
        </div>
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

**ROUTES**

```
Route::get('/fileUploader', 'channelController@viewFile');

Route::post('fileUploader', array(
    'as' => 'fileUploader',
    'uses' => 'channelController@showfileupload',
));
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function showfileupload(Request $request){
   $file = $request -> file('image');
   dd($file); // This work well for me and return information about the image
}
```

Do copy and past! i hope it work, let me know any error and result!

Comment: I'm getting  null value